# Push_back doesn't work

Tags: ros, points, array, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,
i'm writing a node that could save 3 coordinate and then add a point to a pointcloud.
i'm trying to use pushback for the array of points in the cloud, this is the code:

```
struct stru
{
   float x,y,z;
};

sensor_msgs::PointCloud output;

mypoints.x = input->pose.position.x;
mypoints.y = input->pose.position.y;
mypoints.z = input->pose.position.z;
output.points.push_back(mypoints);
```

and the catkin_make give me this error:

```
/home/jacopo/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/svocloud.cpp: In member function ‘void SubAndPub::callback(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/jacopo/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/svocloud.cpp:56:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> > > >::push_back(stru&)’
/home/jacopo/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/svocloud.cpp:56:39: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:826:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> > >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> >]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:826:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘stru’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> >&}’
```

i'm missing something about push_back but cannot understand what....
do somebody could help me??

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201256/push_back-doesn%27t-work/) by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2015-01-19

Post score: -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

push_back expects the pushed data to be of the type defined by the std::vector that handle the array. PointCloud points array is defined as an array of geometry_msgs/Point32 so you have to use it instead of your custom data structure.

PointCloud doc : http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html

EDIT :
If you want to display several markers, you may look at MarkerArray message. If you just want to convert from Point to Point32, you may just fill fields with the corresponding data (the structure are the same), and checking that your conversion doesn't lose data (from float64 to float32)

You should really have a look at message documentation : http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs, http://wiki.ros.org/sensor_msgs, ... so that you can choose the relevant message for you application.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-01-19**:
yes that's right!
but i'm doing that for converting the coordinate from a marker, for including it into a pointcloud.
the pointcloud rappresent it with the geometry_msgs/Point32, but in the marker the coordinate are
geometry_msgs/Point.
how i can convert one in another format??

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2015-01-19**:
Edited my answer, see above.

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-01-19**:
reading about the pointcloud messages, i find this: "It is recommeded to use Point wherever possible instead of Point32."
can i choose that after using pointcloud?? how??
if that is not possible, i'm trying to do what you've said, but x=y where x is float32 and y float64 is not working,how i can do?